# Windows Explorer detected wrong drive total space

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, windows-explorer, usb-flash-drive

Note: This is not a duplicate of:

- [Windows explorer displaying wrong free space](https://superuser.com/questions/586534/windows-explorer-displaying-wrong-free-space)
- [Windows Server 2008 r2 reports wrong hard drive free space](https://superuser.com/questions/514438/windows-server-2008-r2-reports-wrong-hard-drive-free-space)
- [Windows 10 reporting wrong hard disk free space](https://superuser.com/questions/1118614/windows-10-reporting-wrong-hard-disk-free-space)
- [Drive Space Inconsistently reported](https://superuser.com/questions/1388640/drive-space-inconsistently-reported)

I was manually writing boot sector for my USB drive. And yes, it show up as FAT, but the total space was 10.1 MB, while HxD and Disk Management show as 3.77 GB.

Screenshot:
[image: The pointed line was the device was the problem.]

Comment: You might just reformat the disk in Disk Management.

Comment: Yes, but the boot sector was FAT, while Windows formatted as FAT16 and also asked for "incompatible with previous versions", and FAT, FAT16, FAT32 was same as FAT.